# How should I implement a dynamic list of builders?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I'm writing code that builds a UserProfile object from a Map of Strings. At the moment I'm dividing the code into several [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) objects that build parts of the user profile, something like this:

```
public UserProfile getUserProfile(int id) {
  Map<String, String> data = this.service.getUserProfileData(int id);
  UserProfile profile = userProfileBuilder.build(data);
  profile.setMarketingPreferences( marketingPreferencesBuilder.build(data) );
  profile.setAddress( addressBuilder.build(data) );

  ...

  return profile;
}
```

It would be nice to be able to have a list of builder objects instead so that I can dynamically add additional builders without touch the class and breaking the [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Perhaps something like this, instead:

```
private List<ProfileBuilder> builders;

public void buildBuilders() {
  this.builders = new ArrayList<ProfileBuilder>();
  builders.add( new BasicDetailsBuilder() );
  builders.add( new AddressBuilder() );
  builders.add( new MarkettingPreferencesBuilder() );

  ...

}

public UserProfile getUserProfile(int id) {
  Map<String, String> data = this.service.getUserProfileData(int id);
  UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
  for(ProfileBuilder builder : this.builders) {
    builder.build( profile, data );
  }

  return profile;
}
```

Can you see any problems with this approach? Is this strictly the Builder design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use builder/builders only if construction UserProfile is complicated

If you only want rewrite data from Map to fields in UserProfile and you have many fields in UserProfile maybe better solution will be something like: reflection and mapping: key from Map -> setter method in UserProfile

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Construction of UserProfile can be complicated, the class is getting very long with mappings. The above is also a simplification, some entries in the Map can be more Maps. Is there an API that allows me to automatically map values to beans as you propose?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any but JAXB, xtreme and castor do what you want with mapping XML to Java class

Comment: Unfortunately the service I'm using to retrieve user profile data returns a Map, not XML.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes more of a Visitor than a builder. You could do this:

```
interface UserProfileVisitor {
  public void visit(UserProfile profile, Map<String, String> data);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly you think this is a use case for the Visitor? I don't see either `UserProfile` or `Visitor` hierarchies here.